# How do I add a porous texture to a mesh?

Tags: texturing

I want to create a porous bone texture for my mesh. I've tried importing image of bone pores and it looks distorted and bad.

I am a newby, is there something I'm doing wrong?

I tried the noise texture and a few others and they aren't cutting it!

- I need to create a mesh with an appearance of tiny hollow cavities. [image]

Comment: Can you add more detail of what you are doing, and how it looks? (e.g. what do you mean by "they aren't cutting it"?)

Comment: When I viewed this thread, it had 777 views:D

Comment: Check also the Mesh: Tissue add-on http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue

Answer (score 4):

## Using [image textures](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Image):

There are a few things that could be causing your texture to look distorted:

- Ensure that your mesh is [properly UV unwrapped](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping)
- Check that you have UV coordinates selected; in cycles this is accessed with the [*Texture coordinate*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures) node, in Blender Internal it is set in *Texture settings > Mapping*.

## Using [Procedural textures](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Procedural):

As said on the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Procedural):

> Procedural textures are textures that are defined mathematically. They are generally relatively simple to use, because they don't need to be mapped in a special way - which doesn't mean that procedural textures can't become very complex.
>
> These types of textures are 'real' 3D. By that we mean that they fit together perfectly at the edges and continue to look like what they are meant to look like even when they are cut; as if a block of wood had really been cut in two. Procedural textures are not filtered or anti-aliased. This is hardly ever a problem: the user can easily keep the specified frequencies within acceptable limits.

### Blender Internal:

Here is a quick example of a [bump mapped](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Influence/Material/Bump_and_Normal) cloud noise texture:

[image]

To create this:

1. Add a new material
2. Add a new *Clouds* texture
3. In *Texture settings > Influence > Diffuse* disable *Color*, and in *Influence > Geometry* enable *Normal* to use bump mapping. (you may want to scale down the influence a bit, and change the *Method* to *Best quality*)
4. In *Texture settings > Clouds > Basis* change the *Size* value as desired.

### Cycles:

To bump map, simply plug the texture into the *Displace* socket of the *Material output node*.

[image]

Note that this can also be done per shader with the *[Bump](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Bump)* node and the *Vector* input socket of shader nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use volume scatter and volume absorption with a mix of transparency controlled by a texture (for more realism you might want to use more than one texture).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reproduce the way bones are created!

I mean: a bunch of calcium being secreted outside the cells (or tissue) and molding around them... Thats how you get the porous pattern.

Maybe you can create several spheres and place them in a pattern, the create a cube, put the cube inside the pattern and use a Boolean modified to "cut" the cube based on the spheres. After that, apply the boolean modifier and you may get the result you wish.

Answer (score -2):

As to make volumetric porousity on volume level for your bony object ,I found a  useful blog with beautiful open source downloadable plugin AtomBlend,  developed in Sydney by Vavara Efremova under the supervision of Anna Ceguerra, Simon Ringer and  Peter Felfer. It works for Nano particles material research . so can handle enormous number of vertices for visualisation , render and analysis .You can load your object vertics data and make Atomic view and switch halo material (circles as atoms) to Vertex duplication (spheres as atoms) by switching On Vertex Duplication in the object tab.

http://www.peterfelfer.org/?p=214
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The link here is to a website that is no longer registered to anyone.